# JQuery is not displaying dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have navigation that contains products that users can click to find out more information. The information for each product is then displayed underneath dynamically using jquery. The jquery is supposed to grab the content from within the #guts tag of the linked page and load it into the main page once the user has selected what they want to look at. For some reason when I try and do this the div moves around but no content loads.

Here is my HTML:

```
          <div id="page-wrap" style="margin-top:0px;">
                <header>
                    <nav id="printProducts">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="../php/businessCards.php">Business Cards</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="../php/letterheads.php">Letterheads</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../php/leaflets.php">Leaflets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="print.html">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
            </header>
                <section id="main-content">
                    <div id="guts" style="height:300px;background-color:#999999;">
                        <p>We specialize in business stationery from your everyday business cards through to complex brochures, leaflets, forms, pads and exhibition products. </p><br/>

                </section>
        </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Along with jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js

Here is my CSS;

```
        #page-wrap{width:400px;
        margin:40px auto 5px;
        background:#fffff;
        padding:8px;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ccc));
        margin-top:60px;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
        -webkit-border-radius:16px;
        -moz-border-radius:16px;}

        #main-content{padding:0px;
        margin-bottom:40px;}

        #printProducts{float:left;
            list-style:none;
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            width:100%;
            margin-left:0%;
            display:inline}

        #printProducts ul li{display:inline;
                clear:both;}

        #printProducts a{display:inline-block;
            *display:inline;
            padding-top:.7em;
            padding-left:.3em;
            padding-right:.3em;
            padding-bottom:.5em;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fff;
            background:#be0d34;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;width:145px;height:9.765625%;float:left;border-left-color:#FFFFFF;border-left-width:thin;border-left-style:solid;border-top-color:#FFFFFF;border-top-width:thin;border-top-style:solid;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);position:relative;}
            #printProducts a:hover{background:#FFFFFF;color:#be0d34;}
            #guts{padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the developer tool tell you? does the request fire and return the required content? are there any errors? is the hashchanged event even triggered? maybe the content is loaded but the `fadeIn()` failed?

Comment: $mainContent, $pageWrap, baseHeight, $el using without declaring how?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me sort it.

Comment: What do you mean by use without declaring? and what affect does that have? sorry im new to jquery.